# System.Exception: Name already exists in the drawings collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, epplus

I am trying to generate bar graph in excel sheet using Epplus library. I have already successfully added a Piechart to the sheet.

```
var chart1 = ws.Drawings.AddChart("xyz",eChartType.ColumnClustered) as ExcelBarChart ;
    chart1.Legend.Position = OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart.eLegendPosition.Right;
    chart1.Legend.Add();
    chart1.SetPosition(1, 0, 1, 0);
    chart1.SetSize(600, 400);
    //chart.Se
    chart1.DataLabel.ShowValue = true;


    chart1.Series.Add(r1, r2);
```

I am casting as ExcelBarChart .
But I am getting error at first line above

> *`System.Exception: Name already exists in the drawings collection`*

I have tried diferent chart type options like ColumnClustered, Barstacked etc but still getting error. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the error - it's not talking about the type of the chart, it's talking about the *name*. Presumably you've already added a chart called `xyz`. Just use a different name instead.

(Reading the error message carefully is always important so that you don't go down blind alleys...)

EDIT: As noted in the comments, the method was being called twice. The first time it would work, but the second time it would fail due to trying to add a second chart with the same name. Options:

- Keep track of how many charts you've created, and name them xyz1, xyz2 etc
- Create a chart name from a Guid or something similar
- Pass the chart name into the method and force the caller to ensure they're unique

Comment: No , the other chart has a different name , not "xyz"

Comment: @mhasan: Well, the exception suggests that *something* is already called `xyz`. I suggest you change it to a string which can't *possibly* already exist in your worksheet.

Comment: Thanks Jon skeet sir , big fan of yours

Comment: @mhasan: I've edited the answer to give a few options for how to solve this.